# Is there a definition for an actively working person?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I would like to ask for a direct or indirect definition that would define the person who is actively working in a company.

For example in Linkedin I've seen the definition as `present` yet it does not fit my intend because I will define a database system with captions which will be shown directly as they are written in database captions.

I would like to come up with a word like this:

```
- Name: Berker Yuceer
- Age: 31
- "Actively Working": True
- Gender: M
- Active: True // CV is Active
```

So `present` not gonna be a good choise and it may lead the meaning `present in life`.

Active also is not a good choise because I am using it to define if that CV is active or not.

Depending on these matter I thought on simply writing `working` but it can be generalized to working on anything.

**Example:** Working on a project.

So I am out of juice to solve this and looking for different ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Employed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/employed) can mean "to provide with a job that pays wages or a salary".  The field could be "currently employed".

Comment: Actually this should have cross the mind yet it seems like I've been focusing in wrong directions. Where simplicity is a measure, this answer is more powerful than it seems. Thank you!

Comment: We all have those moments.  :)

Answer (score 1):

- An actively working person is "employed".
- A more specific term for someone who is working *and earning money*
  is "gainfully employed".

It depends on what you mean by "active", because a person can be "employed" if they have a current contract of employment, yet they may not be "present" at work for a number of reasons - maternity leave, annual leave (vacation), sickness etc.

Also bear in mind that some people use the term "employed" only for persons who work for an employer, and the term "self-employed" for those with their own business.

If your intention is simply to show that a person currently has a job, either employed or self-employed, and are not concerned with whether or not they are on leave for sick/vacation/whatever, then "currently employed" would probably work best, as this focuses on whether or not it is *current* employment, and not who it is for.

Comment: This is more definitive than the first answer yet it is repeating. +1.